# XML schema; multiple from a list of valid attribute values

Tags: xsd, xml-attribute

I'm reasonably new to working with XML schemas, so excuse my incompetence if this is more trivial than I myself believe it must be.

I'm trying to create a required attribute that must contain 1 or more white-space-separated string values from a list. The list is the 4 typical HTTP request methods; `get`, `post`, `put`, and `delete`.

So valid elements would include:

```
<rule methods="get" />
<rule methods="get post" />
<rule methods="post put delete" />
```

Whereas invalid elements would include:

```
<rule methods="get get" />
<rule methods="foobar post" />
<rule methods="get;post;put" />
```

I've tried fooling with enumerations and length, but I don't believe I'm understanding what I need to do (*or for that matter if it is in fact possible, though it seems as though it should be*)

---

This is where I'm at now, thanks to @tdrury:

```
<xs:attribute name="methods" use="required">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
            <xs:pattern value="(?:(?:get|post|put|delete)\s?){1,4}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

Which works, except for repetition (*such as `get get` or `post post post`*) and absent whitespace (*such as `getpost` or `postputdelete`*)

---

**Edit**:

After playing around with this a bit, I came up with an idea: an enumeration of all possible sequences. Thankfully, this list is (*for the time being*) fixed to the four usual transport methods, `get`, `post`, `put`, and `delete`, so I figured:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
    <xs:enumeration value="delete" />
    <xs:enumeration value="put" />
    <xs:enumeration value="put delete" />
    <xs:enumeration value="post" />
    <xs:enumeration value="post delete" />
    <xs:enumeration value="post put" />
    <xs:enumeration value="post put delete" />
    <xs:enumeration value="get" />
    <xs:enumeration value="get delete" />
    <xs:enumeration value="get put" />
    <xs:enumeration value="get put delete" />
    <xs:enumeration value="get post" />
    <xs:enumeration value="get post delete" />
    <xs:enumeration value="get post put" />
    <xs:enumeration value="get post put delete" />
</xs:restriction>
```

Can anyone see a reason that this would *not* be a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After periodically screwing around with this, I came up with this hulk of a pattern; first in PCRE pretty-print:

```
^
(
  (get     (\s post)?    (\s put)?     (\s delete)?  (\s head)?    (\s options)?)
| (post    (\s put)?     (\s delete)?  (\s head)?    (\s options)?)
| (put     (\s delete)?  (\s head)?    (\s options)?)
| (delete  (\s head)?    (\s options)?)
| (head    (\s options)?)
| (options)
)
$
```

And XML compatible:

```
((get(\spost)?(\sput)?(\sdelete)?(\shead)?(\soptions)?)|(post(\sput)?(\sdelete)?(\shead)?(\soptions)?)|(put(\sdelete)?(\shead)?(\soptions)?)|(delete(\shead)?(\soptions)?)|(head(\soptions)?)|(options))
```

This will successfully match any permutation of `get` `post` `put` `delete` `head` and `options`, further requiring that they be correctly ordered (*which is kinda nice too*)

Anyways, in summary:

```
"get post put delete head options" // match

"get put delete options"           // match

"get get post put"                 // fail; double get

"get foo post put"                 // fail; invalid token, foo

"post delete"                      // match

"options get"                      // fail; ordering
```

This pattern doesn't scale the greatest, as each new "token" needs to be included in every group, but given the problem domain is HTTP methods, change is unforeseeable and I figure it should work just fine.

---

Also, here's a quick script (PHP) to generate the pattern:

```
$tokens = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'head', 'options'];

echo implode('|', array_map(function ($token) use (&$tokens) {
    return sprintf('(%s%s)', array_shift($tokens),
        implode(null, array_map(function ($token) {
            return sprintf('(\s%s)?', $token);
        }, $tokens)));
}, $tokens));
```

It omits the outermost `()` because I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: The default glue for `implode()` is an empty string, so you can removed that `null`.

Answer (score 12):

The basic problem can be addressed with enumerations as well:

```
<xs:attribute name="methods" use="required">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:list>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                            <xs:enumeration value="get"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="post"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="put"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="delete"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:list>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

This unfortunately has the same limitation as the `<xs:pattern>` solution and cannot validate that each token in the list is unique. It does however address the whitespace issue (`getpost` would be rejected).

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions as a restriction on a simpleType: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-pattern

I'm not a regex expert but it would be something like this:

```
<xs:attribute name="methods" use="required">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:pattern value='((get|post|put|delete)[/s]*){4}'/>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

Comment: Thanks @tdrury -- That would be close, I modified it to `(?:(?:get|post|put|delete)\s?){1,4}` which works, except for `get get` or `getpost`, etc. There doesn't appear to be a way to invalidate on duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You could deal with whitespaces like this:

(get|post|put|delete)(\sget|\spost|\sput|\sdelete){0,3}

It will not match getpost.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar to what you wanted, but I didn't want any order to be enforced, and I didn't want the pattern to grow exponentially as more possible values were added.

Using your enumeration as the example, the pattern I've come up with goes like this:

```
(?:get|post|put|delete|head|options)(?:\s(?:(?<!.*\bget\b.*)get|
(?<!.*\bpost\b.*)post|(?<!.*\bput\b.*)put|(?<!.*\bdelete\b.*)delete|
(?<!.*\bhead\b.*)head|(?<!.*\boptions\b.*)options))*
```

This part

```
(?:[values])
```

simply requires that at least one of the options are chosen. If no value is also allowed, surround the entire expression with this: `(?:[...])?`

The remainder

```
(?:\s(?:[values-with-restraints]))*
```

allows for zero-or-more whitespace-plus-value combinations. The values are given in this format

```
(?<!.*\b[value]\b.*)[value]
```

which uses negative look-behind `(?<![...])` to make sure that it doesn't already exist previously in the text. I'm using word boundary markers `\b` to make sure that options that are part in others don't cause problems. An example is if you have options `foo`, `bar` and `foobar`, you don't want the option `foobar` to prevent the `foo` and `bar` options from being legal.

Just keep in mind that since this is going into XML, you'll have to replace the `<` character with `&lt;` when you put it into your schema.

Also, final warning, not all regular expression processors support the lookbehind feature.